# Radio Buttons that fill input from value

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ttline2 = $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['TT_Line2']);

    ttline2 = $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['BadgeHolder']; + $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['strap_clip']; + $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['Lanyard'];
    });
```

So my above code goes like this.
I have 3 radio buttons, each radio button has a value, each value needs to add to a input field, the input field is TT_Line2. I can call to a specific field using $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['Lanyard'];. On JSLINT it says it would be better to use dot notation.

Issue,
I cant get this to pass to the input field. Still new to form filling.

here is my HTML code

```
    <tbody><tr valign="top" style="width: 125px; "><td style="width: 125px"><input type="radio" name="FIELD_1366" id="FIELD_1366" value="No"><span>No</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" style="width: 125px; "><td style="width: 125px"><input type="radio" checked="" name="FIELD_1366" id="FIELD_1366" value="BadgeHolder"><span>Yes</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody><tr valign="top" style="width: 125px; "><td style="width: 125px"><input type="radio" name="FIELD_898" id="FIELD_898" value="No"><span>No</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" style="width: 125px; "><td style="width: 125px"><input type="radio" checked="" name="FIELD_898" id="FIELD_898" value="BulldogClip"><span>Yes</span>
    </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody><tr valign="top" style="width: 200px; "><td style="width: 200px"><input type="radio" name="FIELD_1276" id="FIELD_1276" value="No"><span>No</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" style="width: 200px; "><td style="width: 200px"><input type="radio" checked="" name="FIELD_1276" id="FIELD_1276" value="White"><span>White</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" style="width: 200px; "><td style="width: 200px"><input type="radio" name="FIELD_1276" id="FIELD_1276" value="Black"><span>Black</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <div class="fieldSpacer" id="DIV_119"><p class="fieldSpacer">JDELITM</p><p><input value="50-D-EXPKOE-V-F" style="width: 200px; " name="FIELD_119" id="FIELD_119"></p>
     <script language="javascript">
  FieldIDs["JDELITM"] = 119;
     </script>
    <div id="VALID_VAR_119" style="display:none" class="validationError"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed around my script see here.. still no luck.$(document).ready(function() {
    var ttline2 = $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['TT_Line2']).val;

    ttline2 = $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['BadgeHolder'].val + $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['strap_clip'].val + $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['Lanyard'].val;
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.val**   is messing it up..

It should be **.val()**  Instead... Also You are missing some closing **braces )**

Also you are reading textvalue and saving in in a variable...  Storing value into the variable does not mean the value automatically gets updated.. You need to set it explicitly.

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var ttline2 = $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['BadgeHolder']).val() 
         + $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['strap_clip']).val() 
         + $('#FIELD_' +  FieldIDS['Lanyard']).val();

     $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['TT_Line2']).val(ttline2);
 });​
```

**UPDATED CODE**
If you want to add numbers you need to parse them first as the values are stored as string.

```
var FieldIDS = { 'BadgeHolder' : 'Badge'  , 'strap_clip' : 'Clip' , 'Lanyard' : 'Yard' , 'TT_Line2' : 'Line'};

$(document).ready(function() {
     var ttline2 = parseInt($('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['BadgeHolder']).val())
         + parseInt($('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['strap_clip']).val()) 
         + parseInt($('#FIELD_' +  FieldIDS['Lanyard']).val());

     $('#FIELD_' + FieldIDS['TT_Line2']).val(ttline2);
    });​
```

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6ky/3/)

Comment: I added () to .val but it still is having issues adding the value to TT_Line2

Comment: What does your HTML look like

Comment: I have created FieldIds for an example in the fiddle , Use your FieldIDS object .. Chekc the Demo above first

Comment: no luck there, ack i appreciate the help, this program is very difficult to work with

Comment: Just click it. An the values are propopulated .. You need not do anything as there is no event associated with it

Comment: For instance Field898 up top corresponds to Lanyard field with is ($('#FIELD_' +  FieldIDS['Lanyard']), this parses all the fields its related to such as "no" "white" "black" <- so i just need this one field 'lanyard' which will pull all the fields of "no" "white" or "black".. Its very confusing belive me.

Comment: im looking at the input field and the values are not getting passed to it.

Comment: The program can only order if it has the value.

Comment: Where is FieldIDS['BadgeHolder'] ,FieldIDS['strap_clip'] , FieldIDS['Lanyard'] , FieldIDS['TT_Line2']  coming from

Comment: They exist inside the program which holds all the values of those, so badgeholder has values no or yes on field 1366, thats what i mean the program holds the values on these fields you have to grab the field to pass it, i may need to try the forum on the website for the program.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you have given the same ID to the sam e group of radio buttons.. Avoid that... Try using Name Field Instead.. I will write the up the required code

Comment: Its not me applying the field number its the program. Sorry for all the hassle what you did worked, its the program being asinine.

Comment: Most brobably it was because you had radio buttons with same id's and the value always selected was the first in th egroup.. I tried using the name and checked property instead.. Chekc and let meknow if this works